# Why is this code outputting random garbage values at the end?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, garbage

I was solving a problem on codeforces, but I keep running into unwanted garbage values as output. What can I do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main(){


    int n, k;

    cin >> n >> k;

    char password[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){

        password[i]= 'a' +  i%k;

    }

    cout << password;

}
```

I can't figure out what to do. It's driving me nuts!

Comment: `password` is not 0 terminated so it will keep printing until it finds a 0 or crashes or whatever other undefined behavior happens. Do yourself a favor and learn to use `std::string` instead.

Comment: Please note: [your code isn't valid c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard?r=Saves_AllUserSaves)

Answer (score 1):

C-style strings have an issue which is that they must be null terminated. Aka the last character in the string must be `\0` in order to tell where the string end is. This is because a string in `c` could just be a `char*` with no reference of the length. In c++ we prefer to use types provided by the c++ lib, like `std::string`. With `std::string` your code is much simpler:

```
    int n, k;
    std::cin >> n >> k;
    std::string password;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        password += 'a' +  i%k;
    }

    std::cout << password;
```

This code is much cleaner and fully conforms to the c++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string in this case and append to the string or if you want to stick to character you can do this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int n, k;

    cin >> n;
    cin >> k;

    char password[n];
   
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        password[i] = 'a' + i % k;
    }
    // cout<<password<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout<<password[i];
    }
   
}
```

Comment: `char password[n];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time constant, not a runtime variable.  Dynamic arrays are done in C++ by using `std::vector`.  --> `std::vector<char> password(n);`